# How can I run a debounced function from node command line?

Tags: node.js, lodash, debouncing

I know what [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) does. I'd like to trigger it in node (by running a script with `#!/usr/bin/env node`), but I'm having trouble.

The code below **should**:

- Make `doThingAfterDelay()` which runs a simply function after it has been called once and not been called again for 100ms.
- Run `doThingAfterDelay()`
- Sleep (asynchronously) for 15 seconds, giving `doThingAfterDelay()` time to debounce and therefore execute.

However it doesn't work:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console),
  _ = require('lodash')


var doThingAfterDelay = _.debounce(function(){ 
  return 'foo'
}, 100);


log(doThingAfterDelay());

setTimeout(function(){
  log('Sleeping')
}, 15 * 1000)
```

It returns:

```
undefined
Sleeping
```

I expected:

```
foo
Sleeping
```

**How can I make the debounced function run?**

**edit:** I can get the desired output with:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console),
    _ = require('lodash')


var doThingAfterDelay= _.debounce(function(){
    log('foo')
}, 100);


doThingAfterDelay('one', 'two');

setTimeout(function(){
    log('Sleeping')
}, 15 * 1000)
```

But I do not understand why - and it is important that `doThingAfterDelay()` returns a real value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at source code of the [debounce function](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L10434) you can find that it uses `setTimeout` under the hood and therefore has the same mechanic. You can use a callback or Promise to pass value after debounced function will be executed(also if you are using Promise you could make your code look more synchronous with async/await).

```
var log = console.log.bind(console),
    _ = require('lodash')

var delayedResults = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    _.debounce(function(){
        resolve('foo');
    }, 100)();
});

var start = async function(){
    log(await delayedResults )
}

start()
```

Comment: Basically debounced functions(as well as `setTimeout`) doesn't work that way. You cannot stop synchronous code until delayed function will be executed(unless you're using await/async).

Comment: No, if it invoked with delay, it won't return a value.

Comment: I think, from playing around, I understand this answer more. The main thing is to have a **Promise that runs the _.debounce()** as you have in delayedPromise(). I'm going to tweak your answer a little so it resembles the question more but thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, in general, your other part of code should know when debounced function is done so that's what callbacks and promises for.

Comment: Cheers. I use Promises and callbacks a lot but it was hard to understand how they related to _.debounce. Thanks again and have a great day!